# What escape character for fn:replace function

Tags: xslt, xpath, saxon

I have to to change a bad char to a quotation mark but I can't escape this last one.

Doing this doesn't work

```
<xsl:value-of select="fn:replace(prog:intitules/prog:intitule_fr,'¿', '\'')"/>
```

it produces
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Unmatched quote in expression
Same error with double or triple escapes '\' or '\\'.

My editor refuses this alternative syntax:

```
<xsl:value-of select='fn:replace(prog:intitules/prog:intitule_fr,"¿", "'")'/>
```

Any idea ?
Bernard

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:value-of select='replace(input, "¿", "&apos;")'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 2.0+, you can escape an apostrophe within an apostrophe-delimited string literal by doubling it. So try:

```
''''
```

You need to think very carefully about escapes when you're using regular expressions within XPath within XSLT. Why does the character need escaping?

- If it has a special meaning in regular expressions (for example '(') then use a backslash
- If it isn't allowed because of XPath rules (like here), use XPath escaping (write `'O'Neil'` as `'O''Neil'` or `"a="3""` as `"a=""3"""`)
- If it isn't allowed because of XML rules (e.g. "<"), use XML escaping (write `<` as `&lt;`)

The reason this doesn't work:

```
<xsl:value-of select='fn:replace(prog:intitules/prog:intitule_fr,"¿", "'")'/>
```

is that the XML parser is treating the apostrophe within the string literal as marking the end of the value of the `select` attribute. So here you have an XML issue, and under rule 3 you therefore need to use XML escaping (`&apos;`)

Comment: Thanks a lot ( I've spent hours with that !), it works using &#x2BC; replacement or by doubling the apostrophe.  Great.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your files are  utf-8 encoded, you could you try a workaround, using the Unicode *apostrophe* character (hexadecimal `2BC`) instead of *quote* (hexadecimal `27`):

```
<xsl:value-of select="fn:replace(prog:intitules/prog:intitule_fr,'¿', '&#x2BC;')"/>
```

**Edited:** searching a little bit more, I discovered that switching `'` and `"` and using the entity `&apos;` will get the same result, as michael.hor257k proposed meanwhile:

```
<xsl:value-of select='fn:replace(prog:intitules/prog:intitule_fr,"¿", "&apos;")'/>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because the XML parser expands the character reference before XPath parsing, so what the XPath parser sees is the string literal `'''`, which isn't valid XPath.

Comment: @MichaelKay: your comment would be correct in the case I had provided the hexadecimal code of a quote (`&#x27;`) but I proposed to use `&#x2BC;` and not `&#x27;`. I tested it and it works. I get the string litteral `'ʼ'` and not `'''` as you say. If you zoom in, you will see the difference.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Yes, it's valid XPath, the only problem is the OP wanted an x27 character in the output not an x2BC. Given why they wanted it, the substitution may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: I understand. The reason why I proposed the apostrophe instead of the quote is because he is generating French output (`intitule_fr`) and in French (which is my mother tongue), it is better to use an apostrophe than a quote in some cases. As you say: he will decide.

Comment: Thanks a lot ( I've spent hours with that !), it works using &#x2BC; replacement or by doubling the apostrophe.  Great.